# Probability of an Exact Quantity of Fruits randomly chosen using hypergeometric distribution.

Tags: probability, statistics

Say Mandy has 10 types of fruits in her fridge: 4 apples, 3 bananas, 2 mangos, and 1 blueberry.

In a rush to get to school, Mandy randomly selects 4 fruits to pack in her lunch box.

What is the probability that Mandy packed exactly one apple and one banana?

My first thought was to solve this using hypergeometric distribution.

So,

$\frac{\binom{3}{1}\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{2}}{\binom{10}{4}}$ = 0.1714285714

but I've never encountered a multivariate hypergeometric distribution in any lecture and material of my professor so I don't know if this is valid. Is the hypergeometric distribution valid for any number of objects instead of just 2 as long as the numbers all add up? For example, 3+4+3 = 10 and 1+1+2 = 4 so 10C4 in this case?

Comment: This is correct.  "*I've never encountered a multivariate hypergeometric distribution in any lecture and material...*"  But you have learned first principles that you can count things and divide by the total number of outcomes to get the probability given that the outcomes described are equally likely.  Is it unfair to twist the problem slightly to make harder?  No, not really... especially when such a twist is so minor.

Comment: For what its worth, in my first time in a course on probability and combinatorics we were never even told the name "hypergeometric distribution" or "multivariate hypergeometric distribution", yet we were still expected to be able to understand its use and come up with it ourselves when shown the problems of this type for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Your thinking is right, and that is the multivariate hypergeometric distribution. With hypergeometric you have red ones and non-red ones, but it can be extended to say red blue and green ones. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#Multivariate_hypergeometric_distribution